# How Can I delay the stream to UIImageview using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer from camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

How Can I delay the stream to UIImageview using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer from camera?

See below how I bind them, but I just can't figure how to delay it (I don't want it in real time)

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to want to remove the preview layer frame you have right now, as there is no method to delay those preview frames out of the box.

You're going to want to create a buffer. If we're talking about a few frames, you could have a NSMutableArray that you're filling up on one end with UIImages while you're feeding your image view from the other end.

Your UIImage would come from the didOutputSampleBuffer method, use something like this [UIImage created from CMSampleBufferRef not displayed in UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305862/uiimage-created-from-cmsamplebufferref-not-displayed-in-uiimageview)

Now, few challenges you will have to deal with:

- you're talking about having a multiple seconds delay, 5 seconds would be about 150 frames. Storing 150 UIImage in memory isn't gonna happen, unless they're very tiny and on the latest devices
- You would solve that by saving the images to disk and have your array only store the path of those images instead of the images themselves. Now you're probably going to run into performance issues, as you're going to do read/write operations in real time, your framerate is going to suffer from that
- Because of that bad frame rate, you're going to have to make sure you're not losing synchronization between recorded feed and live feed, otherwise you'll start with a 5 sec delay and end up with a much longer delay

Good luck with that, it can be done with some trade-off (slower frame rate...) but it can be done. (I have done something very similar myself multiple times, can't share the code for IP reasons).