# Binarize pixel data for QR Code Reader

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

How can I binarize the pixels in a CMSampleBuffer received from:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {}
```

I am writing an app to recognize whenever a QR finder mark appears and I would prefer to use one of apple's Core Image filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd try first.  Get the image.  [Here's an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305862/uiimage-created-from-cmsamplebufferref-not-displayed-in-uiimageview) with some highly voted code to do that.

Pick from any number of image libraries to threshold the image.  [Here's an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992078/converting-a-uiimage-blackn-white-and-not-grayscale-for-using-tesseract) with a link to one that uses OpenGL ES for GPU acceleration.

Comment: iamgeFromSampleBuffer isn't a method in iOS. Also, I read that getting a UIImage from a pixel buffer is a fairly expensive operation. I'm looking to binarize and analyze these pixels in realtime. Is this possible without converting it into a UIImage and going from there?

Comment: yeah - my bad, I was pasting lazily from elsewhere.  See my edit, replacing that with a link.