# Playing CMSampleBufferRef's with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, avplayer

I am working on an OSX video editing app and have a set of CMSampleBufferRef's in an array representing each frame of the video.

I want to render a preview of the video using AVPlayer - is it possible feed in these samples directly into AVPlayer?

I've looked at most of the AVFoundation classes. I know I can use AVAssetWriter to write to a file, but want to avoid this as the user will still be doing more editing (so good to have the raw frame data).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

First of all, you should convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to `CGImageRef`, this will allow you to display frame samples in screen.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335379/457569) has the all necessary code to make this.

About to play with `AVPlayer`, I'm not sure if you really need to do this, since you have full access through your `CMSampleBufferRef` *array* and you are able to convert and render those samples properly, I think is not necessary to put those samples at `AVPlayer`, instead, you can render directly `CGImage` at `CALayer`.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean I will need to write my own custom player to handle the timing of each frame, etc? I will want the video frames to loop over and over again.

Comment: Yes, if you only need to loop through frames, is simple enough to implement by hand :) Have  a nice code.